# how to save function arguments into a variable in PHP

Tags: php, function, callback, arguments

Is there a way to save the arguments I am going to use in a function into a variable?

Example, if a function requires:

```
function foo($string, $callback_function) {
    //
}
```

How can I save

```
 $arguments = $string, $callback()
```

So that I can

```
foo($arguments)
```

Is this possible? How? And what does this method called?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use call_user_func_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
<?php
$arguments=array($string,$callback);
call_user_func_array('foo',$arguments);
```

Comment: are there any other method? because the function is a method of a class 

`Model::blah()->foo($arguments);`

?

Comment: You can call static methods on classes like so:
`call_user_func_array('Model::blah', $arguments);`
And on instantiated objects by passing an array: `call_user_func_array(array($model,'blah'), $arguments);`